# iPad: can I reuse an ADInterstitialAd if I present it modally? If not, why am I getting throttling errors?

Tags: ipad, iad

I'm a little unclear on what the best practice is around modal display of `ADInterstitialAd`. Currently, this is what my ARC-enabled app does with development iADs:

1. On startup, my app allocs an `ADInterstitialAd` and keeps a reference to it.
2. After some user interaction, my app modally displays the `ADInterstitialAd`.
3. When `interstitialAdDidUnload` is called, my app nils the reference from step #1, effectively causing ARC to release the `ADInterstitialAd`.
4. My app then allocs `ADInterstitialAd`, and stores that reference for future use.

Steps 2-4, rinse and repeat.

I implemented that way because I found that if I skipped step #3 (never releasing `ADInterstitialAd`), the **next** time I modally displayed the ad, a user could not interact with the ad, effectively stopping my app from being useful.

Apple's documentation for [`interstitialAdDidUnload`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/ADInterstitialAdDelegate_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ADInterstitialAdDelegate/interstitialAdDidUnload%3a) says:

> Your implementation of this method should release the ad object.

To me, I read that as saying my 1-4 sequence above is correct. However, I am getting a lot of throttling errors from the iAd [Test] Network. My hope is that I am getting these errors simply because it is the test network - but my concern is that I'm somehow invoking throttling because I'm not reusing the ad.

I'm not sure. Any ideas/enlightenment?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can only present one every 5-15 minutes as per http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html

So what I do in my apps is create an ADInterstitialAd property on my app delegate and schedule a 5 minutes timer to realloc it.

I set my delegate to it on viewwillappear.

Then in - (void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd the first thing I do is nil out that property. Then when displaying the ad, if I have an add and its loaded I show it otherwise skip it.

Also you cannot reuse the same ADInterstitialAd, ever, according to their documentation.

Comment: Interesting. Though I don't believe that documentation is saying the developer is limited to showing an ad once every 5-15 minutes. I think it only is saying that the ad content expires every 5-15 minutes. I don't think expiration implies limitation. But perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I know what you mean, but their throttling errors are caused by requesting too frequently.